# Should I store default behavior in data?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

By default I send invoices to the customer’s billing address. When a customer prefers an e-mailed invoice, I store the desired address in a “Invoice Delivery Preferences” table.

**Should I also be storing instances of the default behavior here? That is, should customers who are fine with the mailed invoices have rows with their unique billing addresses in this table?**

[A similar question was answered “No”, but their defaults were actually identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701692/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-default-values-in-a-database) – for me, it’s only the process that’s a default, since customers have unique billing addresses.

My concern is that if I wanted change my default behavior after storing these instances as rows, I’d have to update a huge number of them. Right now I could change default behavior by telling 1 COBOL routine to grab something other than the billing address, and send that to the print/e-mail server.

**Outcome: I decided to store the instances of default behavior in the table, and add a "Source" column identifying each row as "System Default" or "Customer Preference"** This consolidated the information, and made the invoicing process consistent, at least from a "tables used" perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something to be said for a process that works one and only one way.

Processes that work one and only one way are usually easier to build, easier to troubleshoot, easier to maintain, and easier to review. (You can often just look at the code and say, "Yup. That's right.")

Although the cognitive load is low with just this one question, a real-world system could have hundreds or thousands of similar design points. Taking a common approach pays off substantially in complex systems.

This is kind of a "Put all your eggs in one basket, after you've made sure you've got a really, really good basket" strategy.

But because SQL databases are so flexible, you can probably get a lot of the benefits from just creating a view that selects the right addresses from the two tables. Then all application code could just read that view. To keep up with changing requirements, just change the view.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have assumed that a COBOL program is hitting a SQL database, but I'll let my answer stand as it is anyway.