# How to instantiate a model object with attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, model, initialization

I would like to instantiate a model object specifying some attributes. For instance

```
post = Post.new
```

should set post.vote_total to 0. I tried to do this in the initialize method but it seems it's not working :

```
def initialize()
    vote_total=0
end
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Pass an attributes hash to the object, as in:

```
post = Post.new(:vote_total => 123, :author => "Jason Bourne", ...)
```

If you're new to Ruby on Rails, you'll probably want to read the **[Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-model)**, which covers this and many more useful Rails idioms in some detail.

Comment: Ok thank you, yes i used this as an example but what if i want to do more sophisticated instanciations like when i want that Vote.new(post) should automatically increment the vote_total of post ?

Comment: In that case it probably makes more sense to make a method on your Vote model, like Vote.add_post(post) and internally the `add_post` method can increment the vote_total.

Answer (score 2):

I would use callbacks:
[Available Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

```
class Post
   before_save :set_defaults

   def set_defaults
      self.vote_total ||= 0
      #do other stuff
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the database to store default values for you

```
class AddColumnWithDefaultValue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :vote_total, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

Or for an existing table:

```
class ChangeColumnWithDefaultValue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_default(:posts, :vote_total, 0)
  end
  def down
    change_column_default(:posts, :vote_total, nil)
  end
end
```

There's a lot of debate about [storing default values in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701692/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-default-values-in-a-database) though.